# Ubuntu22 DNS broken after power short

Tags: 22.04, dns, resolv.conf

After a blackout, I had to `fsck` the partition to be able to login. After that, the clock was a few hours off, which caused the internet not to work. Eventually I got the time correct, but the internet still doesn't connect. It's a DNS problem, because I can't `ping google.com` but `ping 8.8.8.8` works.

```
resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: missing

Link 2 (eno1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlx9cefd5fe6a19)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 10.0.0.138
                2a06:c701:4e0b:b000:2b8:c2ff:febb:4c26 2a06:c701:ffff::1
                2a06:c701:ffff::2
    DNS Domain: local

Link 4 (lxcbr0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

`ls /etc/resolv.conf` no such file

Comment: Can you update question with output of `resolvectl status` and `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: How do you connect to Internet … If your connection gets IP and DNS servers through DHCP from your router like most home connections, then it might be that your router also got messed up in the blackout  and you need to fix it.

Comment: I added the full resolvectl. I tried resetting the router also other devices work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `/etc/resolv.conf` file isn't setup properly. By default, this should be a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, which is a file that defines the local caching stub resolver. Not sure why this isn't setup for you. Anyway, enter the following on the command line to create the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then run the following to restart systemd-resolved:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resloved
```

After that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thx that worked. I will hand you the bounty. I was about to switch over to Debian

Comment: @YehudaClinton Glad it worked out.